# Long CoreData predicate to match multiple terms to attribute + relationships

Tags: core-data, ios11, swift4, xcode9

I’m using swift 4, Xcode 9, iOS 11

I am continuing to learn about CoreData via tutorials and Q&A posts, but I can’t seem to figure out how to answer this question.

I have a CoreData entity with one attribute and 12 relationships to different entities that each contain 1-3 attributes. This is because any given object within the main entity can have multiple additional details within each related entity.

I would like for the user to be able to search and match nearly anything within the database. My current attempt loops through the main entity with a FetchRequest and within each loop matches relationships. This works but is (as expected) somewhat slow.

I tried using a predicate laid out something like this: “name contains TERM OR ANY relation.name contains TERM......”
But this grew into a long predicate and took 30+ seconds to load per fetchrequest. Much slower than without a predicate.

How do I essentially search the entire database more efficiently? Is there a better way to write the predicate? Is there a better way to design my data model?

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: have you tried 12 different fetchRequests and then merging the lists?

Comment: Good call, thanks. That’s on my list of things to try. I’ll report back when I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 month later, the solution was to split up the fetchRequests and add a predicate to each one individually. Furthermore, this allowed me to choose whether a specific related entity required BEGINSWITH[cd] or CONTAINS[cd].

To recap:

- One long predicate lagged for ~30 seconds
- A combined predicate was no better
- Splitting the fetchRequests up and adding a small predicate to each one resulted in zero UI lag searching all 12 relationships.

Many thanks to Jon Rose for the suggestion.